# How to keep state update in ReactJS using Context with Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update my user.cart which is array of objects. When I push new item in cart it's okay till I reload the page. How can I keep the state updated ?

Here is my function:

```
const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);

const addToCart = (userId, product) => {
        fetch(`${API}/cart/usercart`, {
            method:"POST",
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify([userId, product])
        })
        .then(() => {
            const newArr = user.cart.concat(product)
            setUser(oldState => ({
                ...oldState,
                cart: newArr
            }))
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

    }
```

Here is my UserContext:

```
const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${API}/auth/user`, {
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then (response => response.json())
        .then (response => {
            setUser(response.user)
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.error (error);
        });
    }, [setUser])

    return (
        <UserProvider value={{user, setUser}}>
            {props.children}
        </UserProvider>
    )
}   

export default UserContextProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through this before the question  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/state-management-with-react-hooks/

Comment: My authentication is working and I can access the user data, so my context is correct, but the way I update user state is wrong somehow.